# Algorithm to transform symmetric shapes/matrices into a standart one

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Take the letter F. By turning it 90 degrees and mirroring top to bottom you can create $8$ F shapes.
Let's say you represent those letters F by matrices:

$$F_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad F_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ F_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad F_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$F_4 =
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad F_5 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ F_6 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad F_7 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is there an algorithm that when applied to any of those matrices returns the same matrix?

My gut says to transform F into all $8$ shapes, calculate the center of mass from the matrix coordinates and then pick the one with the lowest center of mass to be the output.
Sadly, I have no idea how to prove that this works and it seems like there might be a better way. Also the algorithm should work for any $A\times A$ matrix and not just with F shapes.

This is my first post on Math.StackExchange, I am thankful for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you need a way to choose a representative from class of equivalent matrices.

Center of mass will work if it's different for all $8$ transformations - it's equal to it been not on horizontal or vertical line through center.

However, if you just need any algorithm, it's probably simpler to choose say lexicographically smallest matrix - equivalently, write all elements from matrix in line in some fixed order (for example, left-to-right, top-to-bottom), interpret it as binary number and choose matrix corresponding to the smallest number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll probably go for the binary number approach but I will give it another try to find something else via google. Can you recommend some keywords for my search?

Comment: I don't know if there is any general theory for such problems. May be something in coding theory, but I am not sure.